# Trying to understand why space is missing via Storage Spaces

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

I have a problem with Storage Spaces.

Initially, I had 4x 8TB hard drives and I decided to make a nearly 32TB simple (no parity etc) storage space with this. I let it set its own maximum, and it did nothing to warn me that I wouldn't be able to add additional drives to take the maximum beyond 31.8Tb, because it uses a default cluster size.

Anyway, I added a 5th drive, and hit upon the problem, so I removed the 5th drive from the space, created a new storage space with the intention of copying over 8TB of data, then removing a drive from pool 1 and adding it to pool 2, repeated.

I created this second pool with a much greater maximum size (I wanted to make a 100TB one, but was told this was not allowed... limitation of Windows 10 not using 64K cluster sizes?), anyway, I created the new one to be around 60Tb with one usable 8Tb drive. I copied 8Tb of data to it from my existing storage space, and I can't remove any drives from it.

Whilst Windows reports that I have 15.4TB of used space with 16.4TB available, and 31.8TB total, The Storage space utility reports that 23.3TB of the 29.1TB pool capacity has been used.

I have tried these commands with no luck:

- `Optimize-StoragePool`
- `Optimize-Volume D -ReTrim -SlabConsolidate`

Can anyone give me a reasonable explanation as to where this additional space has gone, and more to the point, how should I proceed with non-destructively creating a single virtual drive that is at least as big as 5x 8TB?

This screenshot shows the phenomenon:

[image]